# how to remove special characters and to get two dates from given string?

Tags: java

how to remove special characters and to get two dates from given string?

```
public class Remove {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="[From:14 02 1986,To:14 02 2016]";
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the width/format of your input date string always the same?

Comment: I might start by splitting the string by `,` then each of the resulting strings by `:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Or use a regex, or a series of substrings.  Without further information, we don't know.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was going down the simplest route, but they are all viable options :P

Comment: Here is a regex pattern to parse: From:(\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d\d\d),To:(\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d\d\d)

Comment: *"special characters"* - which are?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Remove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="[From:14 02 1986,To:14 02 2016]";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile("From:(\\d\\d \\d\\d \\d\\d\\d\\d),To:(\\d\\d \\d\\d \\d\\d\\d\\d)");

        Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("From date : " + m.group(1) );
            System.out.println("To date   : " + m.group(2) );
        }else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to get the dates;

```
String[] dates = s.split(",");
```

That will give you a string array `["From:14 02 1986", "To:14 02 2016"]` then clean the unnecesary text from splits;

```
for (int i = 0; i < dates .length; i++) {
    dates[i] = dates[i].substring(dates[i].indexOf(":") + 1)
}
```

This will remove "From:" and "To:" from array, making it:`["14 02 1986", "14 02 2016"]`, then cast them to DateTime using [DateFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html);

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MM yyyy");
for (String date: dates) {
    println(formatter.parseDateTime(date))
}
```

Edit: just saw the square brackets at the beginning and end of your string, you can remove them in same manner.